# Do non-combat adventures benefit from +meat% buffs?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

Do non-combat adventures benefit from +meat% buffs? I really don't want to waste my last 4 turns of +200% meat drops from monsters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+Meat only affects meat drops from monsters. Meat gained from non-combat adventures is mostly pre-determined or selected from a range, though still not affected by +Meat modifiers.